# Building i2c-tools on android

Tags: android-build

I'm trying to integrate i2-tools on Android build system. I have modified the Android.mk as referred from the blog on internet but I could not see my files getting compiled.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(KERNEL_DIR)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tools/i2cbusses.c tools/util.c
LOCAL_MODULE := i2c-tools
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=tools/i2cdetect.c
LOCAL_MODULE:=i2cdetect
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=libc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := i2c-tools
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(KERNEL_DIR)/include
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=tools/i2cget.c
LOCAL_MODULE:=i2cget
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=libc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := i2c-tools
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(KERNEL_DIR)/include
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=tools/i2cset.c
LOCAL_MODULE:=i2cset
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=libc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := i2c-tools
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(KERNEL_DIR)/include
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=tools/i2cdump.c
LOCAL_MODULE:=i2cdump
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=libc
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := i2c-tools
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(KERNEL_DIR)/include
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Nanda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had test it on my environment, it can compile `i2c-tools`, using the following site for reference:
http://boundarydevices.com/i2c-tools-under-android/

The steps to compile are:

1.enter AOSP.

2.`$ source build/envsetup.sh`

3.`$ lunch xxxxx`

4.copy i2c-tools-3.1.0 folder to AOSP/tools/external

5.create Android.mk file (content same as your) in i2c-tools-3.1.0

6.enter i2c-tools-3.1.0 folder,then type $mm

7.you will see the i2ctools was builded in out/target/product/xxxx/system/bin/i2cset

Answer (score -1):

If you want appiled them into existing system using adb:
after compile use:

```
adb root
adb push i2cdetect \system\bin
```

...
for all other apps i2c*

Regards
Mikołaj